# Paginating an SSRS 2012 report that has two groups in it

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, row-number

I have a report that has two row groups: name and category.  What I want to do is have the report start a new page after 25 names.  I have tried the RowNumber method, but that doesn't seem to work very well in a multiple row group situation as it seems to page after each name and it loses the category grouping.  Is there anything I can do to get the paging that I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want this to use as a group by an expression, although I have not used it myself so I would test it first.

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/25)
```

That would be your grouping.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work for the situation I described.  I wind up getting a new page for every name.

Comment: Hmmm, you may have to do it in the SQL then or add a SCOPE to the RowNumber expression.  1. For Row Number you can add a scope of the grouping in a comments.  Like RowNumber("YourGrouping"), this may help.  2. For SQL you can attempt a windowed statement.  You would need to find a count of sub groups, divide by twenty five, determine scope of page, add a one since first divisibility will yield zero: (this would be a column in a select statement):  (row_number() over(partition by GroupID order by ItemID) / 25) + 1

Answer (score 0):

this case is simple

go to the properties

and find

Report

Page--->InteractiveSize---> Height

Change the height properties by 5.5 and you will be able to show 20 rows per page

you can play with the height until get 25 rows per page